# Property or method "title" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have parent and child components and I am trying to pass props between them. the parent is called links and the child is link-encoded. I have the child like this in the html template

```
<links-encoded title="hellooo"></links-encoded>
```

and in vue file for the parent i have

```
data() {
    return {

        title:"helloooo"
}
```

on the child vue i have

```
export default class LinksEncodedComponent extends Vue {
    props: ['title']
}
```

and in the child html

```
      <p>{{title}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper way to bind `title` data property of the parent to the `title` prop of a child:

`<links-encoded :title="title"></links-encoded>`

Answer (score -1):

fixed i had to put props: ['title'] inside @Component()